# Play RTMP stream from command-line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, audio

I've managed to get [flvstreamer](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/flvstreamer) to read a radio station's [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) stream with the options `--live -r [url]`, and it outputs what I guess is the raw audio data + stream info to stdout.

Can I make it play the stream through my speakers, from the command-line?

Possibly by sending sending the raw audio data to `mplayer` or something else. Thanks.

---

I got it to work with the command `./flvstreamer_x86 --live --quiet -r [url] --buffer 3000 | mplayer -vo null -`, **but it quits after a couple of seconds to a couple of minutes**. I added `--buffer 3000` to imitate what I saw when tracing the original Flash player with Wireshark. These are the last rows of output.

```
[pulse] working around probably broken pause functionality,
        see http://www.pulseaudio.org/ticket/440
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse'
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
FAAD: Failed to decode frame: Maximum number of bitstream elements exceeded
A:16866.9 ( 4:41:06.9) of 0.0 (unknown)  8.1%

Exiting... (End of file)
```

This was with flvstreamer 1.81. I couldn't get it to work with any version above, they just output

```
FLVStreamer v2.1c1
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
ERROR: rtmp server sent error
Starting Live Stream
FLV☺♣               Metadata:
  audiodatarate         48.00
  audiosamplerate       44100.00
  audiocodecid          10.00
[stripped]
```

How can I make it play continuously? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `| mplayer -`?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the suggestion, please see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've made it work with 1.81 now :)

`./flvstreamer_x86 --live --quiet --buffer 3000 -r [url] | mplayer -vo null -idle -`

I added the `-idle` to stop it from exiting, I guess the problem was that flvstreamer needed to buffer and mplayer didn't receive more data, so it quit.